# Are there philosophies in which "coercion" and "imposition" of belief are justified?

Tags: ethics

If someone has the potential to do something immoral, is there a philosophy in which it's okay to physically or verbally "force" them to stop before they do the immoral thing?

What about "imposition" of belief? One believes something is moral. Another believes that same thing is immoral. Is there a philosophy in which it is okay for one to physically or verbally "impose" their belief on another?

Comment: Of course, most flavors of consequentialism would justify whatever is needed for the common good, and even if it is for one's own good, egoism is ethics too. Is there a question beyond that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "imposion of believe". We can try to impose silence on someone else. We can try to shame the other person.

Comment: You speak about immoral acts as if that immorality was an absolute. Can you clarify that?

Comment: A distinction ought be made here between passive restraint and active force. A barrier (such as a wall) preventing an immoral act (such as invasion of privacy) is a passive restraint. Then there is active force (such as a preemptive strike). Another important question here is *excessive* use of restraint or force. In both cases, excessive application causes more harm than it prevents, by hindering freedom or inflicting direct damage. Information too can be controlled passively (denying access) or actively (removing or corrupting), including excessively.